# Case-when or if-then to control table creation in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a handful of data sources that I'd like to apply the same analyses to and eventually load into a larger table database (`uniformtable`). Different sources contain different columns, and sometimes sources involve crosswalk files that I need to join. I'd like to have one query that converts all sources' data into `uniformtable` formatting, based on a unique key for each source. Something along the lines of this:

```
case when source.sourceid = 1 then
create uniformtable as 
select column1a as uniforma, column1b as uniformb, sourceid from source
else
when source.sourceid = 2 then
create uniformtable as
select column2a as uniforma, column2b as uniformb, sourceid from source
end;
```

I've tried using if-then and case-when to accomplish this, but I get syntax errors pointing to the very start of my query. Does Redshift allow you to use if logic for this kind of control?

Answer (score 0):

No, this logic is not permitted.

`CASE` statements are only valid within a `SELECT` statement.

You would need to perform this logic external to Amazon Redshift, and then just send the final SQL to create the table.